# how to get checkout details from paddle in mac app?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have integrated my mac app with paddle this what i followed from documentation and integrated but what i want when user purchases from here i want all the order details.

```
    // Your Paddle SDK Config from the Vendor Dashboard:
    NSString* myPaddleProductID = @"12345";
    NSString *myPaddleVendorID = @"56791";
    NSString* myPaddleAPIKey = @"abc123def345hij678";

    // Populate a local object in case we're unable to retrieve data
    // from the Vendor Dashboard:
    PADProductConfiguration *defaultProductConfig = [[PADProductConfiguration alloc] init];
    defaultProductConfig.productName = @"My v4 Product";
    defaultProductConfig.vendorName = @"My Company";

    // Initialize the SDK Instance with Seller details:
    Paddle *paddle = [Paddle sharedInstanceWithVendorID:myPaddleVendorID
                                                 apiKey:myPaddleAPIKey
                                              productID:myPaddleProductID
                                          configuration:defaultProductConfig];

    // Initialize the Product you'd like to work with:    
    PADProduct *paddleProduct = [[PADProduct alloc] initWithProductID:myPaddleProductID productType:PADProductTypeSDKProduct configuration:nil];

    // Ask the Product to get it's latest state and info from the Paddle Platform:
    [paddleProduct refresh:^(NSDictionary * _Nullable productDelta, NSError * _Nullable error) {
           // Launch the "Product Info" gatekeeper UI with buy, activate, etc:
        [paddle showProductAccessDialogWithProduct:paddleProduct];
```

however in documentation for custom implementation by using below block we can get but i want by using `showProductAccessDialogWithProduct`

```
[paddle showCheckoutForProduct:paddleProduct options:nil checkoutStatusCompletion:^(PADCheckoutState state, NSDictionary * _Nullable checkoutData) {
    // Examine checkout state to determine the checkout result
}];
```

Any Suggestions ?

Thanks In Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

So i got the answer till V4.0.9 we cannot get the details it is included after v4.0.10.

All you need is `PADProductDelegate`

`-(void)productPurchased:(PADCheckoutData *)checkoutData`

using this delegate method you can get checkoutdata and if you need order details 
get `checkout_id` from checkoutdata and pass it on below api.

`https://checkout.paddle.com/api/1.0/order?checkout_id=xxxxxxxxx`